# Debugging WordPress

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, slider

I am developing a WordPress website. I need a slideshow in my page. I already created a slideshow post, and I have the code for the slideshow. My slider just keeps loading and never display the picture. I am checking the script `slider.php`. Below is an excerpt. I try to test the value of $url. But it doesnt work.

1. Why the value of $url are not showing?
2. Is there a better way to test the value of `$url` (I already activated the `WP_DEBUGMODE`, but don't know how to use it)

   ```
   $url = get_post_custom_values('my_key');
   foreach ($url as $key => $value) {
       echo "$key  => $value ( 'my_key' )<br />";
   }
   ```

Comment: You can use `var_dump($url);` or `print_r($url);` followed by `exit();` and check your source code at the end.

Comment: @Alex: The code didn't show up because you have it in the list (in the list because directly after the list). For line-breaks you need to have two spaces at the end to see the break. Just some formatting help. You can review all edits, that way you can see how I did it.

Comment: Thank you for your answers.
barell=> I have used your solution, but I still cant see nothing. Am i supposed to look in a file ? Or is the `var_dump` is suppose to display on screen directly ?

Comment: A `var_dump()` will end up on the screen. Depending on how your theme works, you may not see this information unless you browse your source code. I personally use this code when I want to see some info: `<?php printf ("<pre>\n%s</pre>\n", print_r($url, true) ); ?>`

Comment: Thank you, ill try your method. I definitely saw the result of the `var_dump()` in the source code.